# No module called Yum for installtion of mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am installing mysqldb on CentOS but cant. i need to use yum but when i type yum it gives me the following error.

```
root@osp [/home/hmm/RentalWanted]# yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.3 (default, Dec 11 2012, 20:12:43) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I am referring to [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18383) link as Simeon suggested for the solution adn trying to download these rpms

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm 
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-devel-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm 
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm 
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm 
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/tix-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/tix-devel-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/tkinter-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-39.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Error I am getting while downloading is this

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm 
--2014-12-08 01:58:40--  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
Resolving mirror.centos.org... 216.172.56.29
Connecting to mirror.centos.org|216.172.56.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-12-08 01:58:40 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18383) with same problem like your. Try to download this rpm:

python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm

python-devel-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm

python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm

python-tools-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm

tix-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm

tix-devel-8.4.0-11.fc6.i386.rpm

tkinter-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm

yum-3.2.22-39.el5.centos.noarch.rpm

Comment: Thank you! How do I download the rpm? sorry i am new to Linux :(

Comment: I know this is a very silly question but i need to know how do i download the rpm from command line ..

Comment: First you need to do is to learn how to search. Internet is most powerful thing in the world. If you know how to use search engines ... you will be ok :) If you don't know ... you will ask somebody always :)

Comment: I am still having problems with downloading the rpm

Comment: rpm -Uvh python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm
error: open of python-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386.rpm failed: No such file or directory

Comment: How i tell you. If i know fix your problem ... you always will asking for something ... it's not the right way ... the right way is to solve your problem

Comment: I have been trying but failed. see the edits. Plz help